# Is there any way to call and visualize more than the column Adj Close at the same time on python?

Tags: python, regression, finance, stock

I have this part of the code done, but I would like to be able to add more columns like the Volume, Open, High.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
assets = ["LAC", "NIO"]
weights = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
stockStartDate = "2016-01-01"
today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
today
df = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in assets:
    df[stock] = web.DataReader(stock, data_source ="yahoo", start = stockStartDate, end = today)["Adj Close"]
```

Comment: Please describe what your current code does and what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure you want to do, but in essence if you want to be flexible for visualizing more variables, it's easier to keep the data in a long format, with a column (i used `stock` below) indicating the data source :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

assets = ["LAC", "NIO"]
stockStartDate = "2016-01-01"
today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df = []
for stock in assets:
    x = web.DataReader(stock, data_source ="yahoo",
    start = stockStartDate, end = today)
    x['stock'] = stock
    df.append(x)

df = pd.concat(df)
```

Then pivot it on the fly to plot:

```
df.pivot(values='High',columns='stock').plot.line()
```

[image]

Or use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x = df.index,y = "High",hue = 'stock',data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was brilliant! Thank you so much!! I'm pretty new to python, a lot to learn yet. Thanks a million! Now I think I can manage from here.